# Cannot remove blue "nested" grid/rectangles in QGIS canvas?

Tags: qgis, qgis2threejs

A blue "nested" grid suddenly appeared in the canvas (see image below). I don't know what I did to make this happen and how to get rid of it.

Can anyone please advise me on how to remove this?

[image: printscreen with blue rectangles]

Comment: did you try ctrl-z (or undo in edit menu)?

Comment: As to what this is, I believe you are looking at the iso paper sizes.  see http://www.paperbuyersonline.com/userfiles/image/reference_iso_paper_size.jpg  ,  as to how you got that on your screen or how to remove it, I dont have a clue.

Comment: I'd love to know what you did to get this :) This looks like a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) (this is a data structure used to speed up spatial queries by clumping nearby points together).

Comment: I'd start by disabling/uninstalling all plugins.

Comment: also, I see you're using quite an old version (2.6.0 Brighton)

Comment: Thanks to all of you! Yes, I must certainly update my version, and 'quadtree' is the word. What worked was to shut down QGIS completely. Ctrl-z did not work. Note that it's the 2nd time it happened to me, simply by inadvertently clicking right and left (or something like that) in the canvas (can't remember which tool was active).

Answer (score 3):

This blue quad tree was generated by the qgis2threejs plugin, when selecting `Advanced (quad tree)` DEM resample method.

The quad tree opens along with the plugin window, and should be removed once the plugin window is closed. Minimizing the window won't remove the quad tree. I can't tell from the screenshot if the plugin window is minimized or not, as it doesn't necessarily minimize to the windows taskbar.

Furthermore, once the quad tree option is selected, the only cursur option is to select focal point or rectangle, until another tab is selected. Manually selecting other map navigation tools while the plugin window is open may let you exit the quad tree action and control the map regularly, yet the plugin window is still active.

As of writing, the most recent plugin (1.4.2) and QGIS versions (2.18.10) do not appear to have any issue. I could not find any reference to a quad tree bug in the plugin Issues report or features.

It is generally recommended to always have the latest software version.